# Assembly Language - (Bomb Lab)

Tags: arrays, assembly

I know this kind of question pops up here every once in a while, but I got really confused with this disassembled part when it shows the table in array. What does this represent overall? Does this have hidden characters to the correct string input? I know it is array indexing. It gives you the address of the appropriate character.

```
0x402740 <array.3456>:          2       10      6       1 
0x402750 <array.3456+16>:       12      16      9       3
0x402760 <array.3456+32>:       4       7       14      5
0x402770 <array.3456+48>:       11      8       15      13
```

The disassembled code from <+36> when I did this, `x/16 0x402740`

```
=> 0x000000000040114b <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x000000000040114c <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000000000040114f <+4>:     callq  0x4013ab <string_length>
   0x0000000000401154 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax //expecting 6 character string
   0x0000000000401157 <+12>:    je     0x40115e <phase_5+19>
   0x0000000000401159 <+14>:    callq  0x4016a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040115e <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401163 <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000401168 <+29>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
   0x000000000040116c <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x000000000040116f <+36>:    add    0x402740(,%rcx,4),%edx
   0x0000000000401176 <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000040117a <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
   0x000000000040117e <+51>:    jne    0x401168 <phase_5+29>
   0x0000000000401180 <+53>:    cmp    $0x3d,%edx //how do I find string that matches 0x3d?
   0x0000000000401183 <+56>:    je     0x40118a <phase_5+63>
   0x0000000000401185 <+58>:    callq  0x4016a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040118a <+63>:    pop    %rbx
   0x000000000040118b <+64>:    retq
```

Comment: Looks like the array you printed out is a list of 16 integers that is used for some sort of cypher against the lower nibble of each of the characters in your string.

Comment: Links to the source of your images would help. Not everyone knows what Bomb Lab is even if they know assembly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah, that's exactly right, but the problem is how do I find the secret characters?

Comment: @CareyGregory I can add images, but does this help enough? I thought copying and pasting assembly codes here is good enough?

Comment: Posting assembly is perfectly fine. I just meant that a link to something on Bomb Lab would be nice instead of making us google it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken all you need to do here is work backwards. You have a table of numbers. You have a loop that goes through 6 characters looksup that character (lower nibble) in the table and just adds the value retrieved and then compares the sum to 0x3d(decimal 50). Find 6 numbers in the table when added up equal 50 and then find any corresponding letter that maps to each number and enter it as input.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Okay thank you for the tip. Let's say, ajklmn in ascii adds up to 61 (FYI 0x3d is 61), why does this output as 63?

Answer (score 0):

In Assembly, everything is just blob of memory. The only thing that gives meaning to the blob of memory are the instructions executed on it. For example, I can pretty well assume that `array` is an array of ints because
the operation working on it `<+36>` is using a skip of 4 when indexing, which is the size of an integer.

However, I can pretty much guarantee you that there is no string at address 0x3d because that is not a valid location in virtual memory. Instead it is probably an int. I can say that by seeing that it is being compared to `%edx` at `+53` which is also an int. I can tell `%edx` is an int because in `+36` we are adding a number to it, moreover at `+24` it is initialized to zero.

If you are asking what *character* 0x3d is equal to, it is `=` (find it by opening a python shell and typing `chr(0x3d)`). This is still not what  you are looking for. Instead, you are looking for the right input that makes `%edx` equal to `0x3d` after it all.

Comment: C'mon, people. If you're going to downvote, at least leave a comment explaining your decision.

Comment: Get used to it. Many people do that.

Comment: Can anyone delete this question, please? I solved this, but I don't want to post the actual answer here since it was my project assignment.